# defining a new variable equal to the length of two other arrays

Tags: python

This is purely out of curiosity, and I'm definitely over thinking it, but it's something I occasionally bump into and I never like my solution.

Given two lists:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [128, 244, 132, 161]
```

I need to compute a new variable `n`, equal to the length of these lists. I could use `n = len(x)` or `n = len(y)`, but this is explicitly setting `n` equal to one and specifically not the other. I feel like the following does what I want:

```
def common_length(x, y):
    assert len(x) == len(y)
    return len(list(zip(x, y)))
```

But that's clearly overkill. I don't know why this bugs me but I'd like to know what alternatives there are, if any, or if I should just get on with my life by using `n=len(x)`.

Comment: if you are sure about the length of x and y are equal then definitely you can use `n = len(x)` or `len(y)`. doing zip and asset is overkill

Comment: what you are trying to do?

Comment: As you do have working code, but want an alternative solution [codereview.SE] might be a better place for this question.

Comment: @das-g thanks, never used code review. Should I just make a new post or is there a way to transfer this?

Comment: you are checking for this `len(x) == len(y)` if this is true there is no need to do this `len(list(zip(x, y)))` you can directly return length of one of the list

Comment: If the lists *must* always have the same length (presumably because entries at the same index in both lists are used together somehow), you could use a single list where the entries are lists/tuples with the values you want at that same index in both lists. Then there is only one list to take the length of :-) For example `xylist = [ [1,128],[2,244],[3,132],[4,261]]` and use `’len(xylist)`

Comment: Ah, sorry. It'd probably fail the "Is it actual code from a project rather than pseudo-code or hypothetical code?" condition of https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, so maybe it's more on-topic here.

Comment: @barny yes, that's definitely how I prefer thinking about it. But then this is identical to using `list(zip(x, y))` and then taking the len of that.

Comment: @barny why zip, I am still trying to figure out this. If you don't know but zip is a time-consuming task. And why not len(x). why we are trying to make things complicated

Comment: @fffrost it's different in that you'll adapt your code to use the data like this - and when you use this the values are indivisble - thet are always present in pairs. So I'm not suggesting you zip the values together when you need the length, rather that you *use* the values together so there aren't two lists to zip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know for certain that `x` and `y` have the same length, but want to make it explicit in the code (e.g. for sake of future maintainance) that you could have chosen either of them, then you could of course add a comment:

```
n = len(x)  # also equals len(y)
```

If you suspect that they might not be equal, and you want to raise an exception if they are not, then you should consider what exception is most appropriate.  The use of `assert` is intended as a debugging aid, so your code should only raise an `AssertionError` in the event that it actually contains a bug.  So if your code ought to be creating `x` and `y` with equal lengths but you want to check that it is actually doing so, then by all means you could use:

```
n = len(x)
assert n == len(y)
```

However, if `x` and `y` derive from user input and the user might have wrongly provided inputs of unequal length, then it would be more appropriate to do e.g.:

```
n = len(x)
if n != len(y):
    raise ValueError('x and y should have equal lengths')
```

None of the above are symmetrical in `x` and `y` to look at, but in all cases it is obvious to the reader that the two lengths are supposed to be equal -- and in the last two it is enforced.  There is little justification in using `len(list(zip(x, y)))` merely for sake of aesthetic symmetry, when it adds unnecessary expense in iterating over both inputs and creating a temporary list.  A cheaper (but still unnecessary) equivalent would be `min((len(x), len(y)))`.

The other thing to consider, of course, is whether the fact that `x` and `y` must always have the same length is indicative of the fact that your data should be organised differently.  For example, depending how you intend to use the data, it might be better to store your data as a list of tuples -- i.e. what your `list(zip(x, y))` would produce:

```
data = [(1, 128), (2, 244), (3, 132), (4, 161)]
```

or maybe as a numpy array:

```
data = np.array([[1, 128], [2, 244], [3, 132], [4, 161]])
```

whereupon your statement just becomes:

```
n = len(data)
```

and the aesthetic gain comes as a natural consequence of actually organising your data in a way that ensures that the constraint of equal length cannot be violated, rather than as a result of contriving to write a symmetrical expression merely for aesthetic purposes.

In the numpy array case, you can also still refer to `x` and `y` separately by creating the relevant slices (recall that in numpy, slices are views of the data rather than copies):

```
x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]
```

though this approach does of course depend on them having the same data type.

Answer (score 0):

It looks pretty simple case:
You have n1=len(x) and n2=len(y)
If n1 and n2 will always be the same, you can use any of these 2 for declaring n
`n=n1` or `n=n2`

If they can be different, it depends on your needs to get the min of max of these 2 with
`n=max(n1, n2)` or `n=min(n1,n2)`
There can be no other case under these parameters